# How can I stop the log output of lightgbm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, lightgbm

I would like to know how to stop lightgbm logging.
What kind of settings should I use to stop the log?
Also, is there a way to output only your own log with the lightgbm log stopped?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can disable lightgbm logging using `verbose=-1` in both Dataset constructor and train function, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1157)

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for 2024 (`lightgbm>=4.3.0`), describing how to suppress all log output from `lightgbm` (the Python package for LightGBM).

#### Answer

If using estimators from `lightgbm.sklearn` estimators:

- pass `verbosity=-1` to estimator constructor

If using `lightgbm.train()`, `lightgbm.cv()`, `lightgbm.Dataset()`:

- pass `"verbosity": -1` through `params` keyword argument

Both interfaces emit a `UserWarning` if they encounter a conflict between keyword arguments and configuration passed other ways (`**kwargs` for scikit-learn, `params` dictionary for `cv()` / `train()`. To suppress those too:

- use `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)`

#### Examples

Using Python 3.11, `lightgbm==4.3.0`, and `scikit==1.4.1`, with the following imports and setup for all examples:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import warnings
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

# create datasets
X, y = make_regression(
    n_samples=10_000,
    n_features=10,
)
```

This `scikit-learn` example with no explicit verbosity control...

```py
model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    num_boost_round=10,
    num_leaves=31,
).fit(X, y)
```

...produces this output...

```
.../python3.11/site-packages/lightgbm/engine.py:172: UserWarning: Found `num_boost_round` in params. Will use it instead of argument
  _log_warning(f"Found `{alias}` in params. Will use it instead of argument")
[LightGBM] [Warning] num_iterations is set=10, num_boost_round=10 will be ignored. Current value: num_iterations=10
[LightGBM] [Info] Auto-choosing row-wise multi-threading, the overhead of testing was 0.000106 seconds.
You can set `force_row_wise=true` to remove the overhead.
And if memory is not enough, you can set `force_col_wise=true`.
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 2550
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data points in the train set: 10000, number of used features: 10
[LightGBM] [Info] Start training from score -1.188321
```

...but with verbosity controls...

```py
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)
model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    num_boost_round=10,
    num_leaves=31,
    verbosity=-1
).fit(X, y)
```

... does not produce any log output.

Similarly, using `train()` with no verbosity controls ...

```py
model = lgb.train(
    train_set=lgb.Dataset(X, label=y),
    params={
        "objective": "regression",
        "num_iterations": 10,
        "num_leaves": 31
    }
)
```

... produces this output ...

```
.../python3.11/site-packages/lightgbm/engine.py:172: UserWarning: Found `num_iterations` in params. Will use it instead of argument
  _log_warning(f"Found `{alias}` in params. Will use it instead of argument")
[LightGBM] [Info] Auto-choosing row-wise multi-threading, the overhead of testing was 0.000136 seconds.
You can set `force_row_wise=true` to remove the overhead.
And if memory is not enough, you can set `force_col_wise=true`.
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 2550
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data points in the train set: 10000, number of used features: 10
[LightGBM] [Info] Start training from score -1.188321
```

...but with verbosity controls...

```py
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)
model = lgb.train(
    train_set=lgb.Dataset(X, label=y, params={"verbosity": -1}),
    params={
        "objective": "regression",
        "num_iterations": 10,
        "num_leaves": 31,
        "verbosity": -1
    }
)
```

... does not produce any log output.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these points.

1. Use "verbose= False" in "fit" method.
2. Use "verbose= -100" when  you call the classifier.
3. Keep "silent = True" (default).