# turn off debug log output of lightgbm sklearn interface

Tags: scikit-learn, lightgbm

How do I turn off debug log output of lightgbm sklearn interface? Tried

```
regressor = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor(verbose=-1)
```

does not work.

```
regressor.fit(verbose=-1)
```

is not accepted.

What I found is through lightgbm itself, not sklearn interface which I want to use.
[How can I stop the log output of lightgbm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980647/how-can-i-stop-the-log-output-of-lightgbm)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

These two mechanisms are enough to suppress all log output from `lightgbm`'s scikit-learn interface

- pass `verbosity=-1` to constructor of estimators like `LGBMRegressor()`
- use `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)`

#### Details

With `lightgbm>=4.3.0`, just passing `verbosity=-1` into the constructor should be sufficient.

Consider this minimal, reproducible example:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

# create datasets
X, y = make_regression(
    n_samples=10_000,
    n_features=10,
)

# create regressor and fit to data
clf = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    n_estimators=10,
    num_leaves=31,
    verbosity=-1
).fit(X, y)
```

With Python 3.11, `lightgbm==4.3.0`, and `scikit-learn==1.4.1`, that does not produce any log output.

The same code but with `verbosity=1` instead produces this output:

```
[LightGBM] [Info] Auto-choosing row-wise multi-threading, the overhead of testing was 0.000161 seconds.
You can set `force_row_wise=true` to remove the overhead.
And if memory is not enough, you can set `force_col_wise=true`.
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 2550
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data points in the train set: 10000, number of used features: 10
[LightGBM] [Info] Start training from score -0.050604
```

As of `v4.3.0`, there is one source of possible log output that cannot be suppressed via the `verbosity` keyword argument. Any parameters passed into `LGBMRegressor()` which don't match its keyword arguments are collected and passed down to `lightgbm.train()`, and `lightgbm` sometimes warns when it uses such values.

Like this:

```py
clf = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    num_boost_round=10,
    num_leaves=31,
    verbosity=-1
).fit(X, y)
```

Produces this:

```
.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightgbm/engine.py:177: UserWarning: Found `num_boost_round` in params. Will use it instead of argument
  _log_warning(f"Found `{alias}` in params. Will use it instead of argument")
```

You can suppress those using Python's warning-control mechanisms, described in the documentation for the `warnings` module ([docs link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-filter)).

Add this prior to calling any `lightgbm` code:

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)
```